# How to run asyncio.run in command line?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, event-loop

I'm learning Python asyncio for a new project and got stuck on this.

In my main.py, I have something like this:

```py
async def main():
    await some_coroutine(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

But I'm wondering how I can run **asyncio.run()** in the command line(I'm building a command line tool)?

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
python3 -m asyncio.run(main.main)
```

However, it works if I just run it as a normal python script:

```
python3 -m main.main
```

But in this case, it won't start an event loop, will it?

Can any Python expert help me understand this? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: "But in this case, it won't start an event loop, will it?" Have you tried it? How would you run a "regular" script that die not invoke asyncio?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I did some manual trace and proved I was wrong, it works as a normal script. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve put the `asyncio.run` in an [`ifmain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html).

Therefore the block will only be executed when you execute that script directly, `python main.py` should launch the event loop.

Comment: Note that an entry point is a different concept, related to packaging.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, true that was a bit of a shortcut, I’ll edit.

Comment: @ljmc, I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, but it's helpful, thank you.